# Why are this queries two left joins returning the same value?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have the query running below...

The problem is `Total Recommendations` is returning the wrong value, it's returning the same value as `Total Contacts`... `Total Contacts` is correct... Why is `Total Recommendations` computing incorrectly? Thanks

```
SELECT 
    ca.id, 
    ca.user_id, 
    ca.account_name,
    COUNT(c.id) AS 'Total Contacts',
    COUNT(pr.id) AS 'Total Recommendations'
FROM connected_accounts ca

LEFT JOIN contacts c
     ON ca.id = c.connected_account_id
       AND c.contact_type = 'email'

LEFT JOIN peer_recommendations pr
     ON ca.id = pr.connected_account_id

WHERE ca.resource_type = 'calendar.readonly'
GROUP BY ca.id, ca.user_id, ca.account_name
ORDER BY ca.id DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`

Comment: Without some sample data showcasing the wrong output, it is hard to predict what is wrong ?

Comment: ...but not that hard

Comment: @Strawberry updating to `COUNT(DISTINCT...` results in both Total fields returning 0

Comment: I cannot emulate that result.

Comment: You can create a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that reproduce the problem. BTW, is it something to do with the `LIMIT 8` in the query?

Comment: @AlonEitan No. The LIMIT would make no difference